# Wordpress show Gallery Title and Captions

Tags: gallery

I would like to show the gallery title together with the captions. Below is my attempt, but I keep getting `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` . I still can't figure it out what went wrong.

single.php

```
<div class="gallery-content">
        <?php 
        add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery', 'fullsize_gallery' );     
        if( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) ) :   

        $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID );

        $image_list = '<ul class="galleryslider" style="display: none;">'; 

        foreach( $gallery as $image ) :
        $image_title = wp_get_attachment_url($image->post_title);
        $image_caption = wp_get_attachment_url($image->post_excerpt);
        // Loop through each image in each gallery
        $image_list .= '<li><a href="'. $image . '" data-lightbox="'.$post->ID.'"><img src="' . $image . '" title="'.$image_title.'"/>'.$image_caption.'</a></li>';
        endforeach; 
        $image_list .= '</ul>';                     
        echo $image_list;                           
        endif;
        ?>
    </div><!-- .gallery-content -->
```

functions.php

```
function fullsize_gallery( $out )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $out['size'] = 'full';
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_post_gallery_images` only returns a singular array of image URLs, so `$image->post_title` etc won't work, hence your error message.

The approach generally is off - you've followed the codex for get_post_gallery_images but that snippet is aimed at re-using the image urls within the post, but outside the gallery output.

`get_attached_media` is more suited here (just a more concise helper than writing $args out for a get-posts call).
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media

If this is a modification to all your galleries then the answer below will show you a much better and more flexible approach (using the post_gallery filter instead).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802157/change-wordpress-default-gallery-output

Comment: Hi Steve82, I have seen the links provided but I still couldn't find my answer. Could you please show me more example?

Comment: Have you tried restoring single.php as it came with your theme originally and then copying the code example in the last link into your functions.php? That would get you started. If you let me know what theme you're using I'll try update the answer with a suitable example.